# onScroll not working in ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

onScroll function not called in ListView. I test it on both android & iOS.
 I'm using a simple code:

```
< ListView
    style={styles.flex1}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow}
    onScroll={() => { console.log('onScroll!'); }}
/>
```

Comment: Did you run `react-native log-ios` or `react-native log-android` to check the logs ? The `onScroll` prop looks correct.

Comment: Same problem, did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Fiden answer worked for me. If it's not working for you, add new question with your code and link it here.

Comment: I am also having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Fidan said, There is no problem with triggering onScroll. The problem was from not seen logs. The problem solved by using `react-native log-ios`.